# Javascript Convert ansi to utf8

Tags: jquery, utf-8, ansi

i'm trying with this plugin jquery.csvToTable to show data from csv to web page , cvs file has encoding ansi with Japanese text , but webpage has encoding utf8 , and js is not working with ansi , how is possible to convert or if exist another method data `$.get(csvFile, function(data) {` data  to utf8 , sorry for my bad English , thanks a lot !

Comment: How are you getting the data? Can you use server side programming?

Comment: no i'm not using server side programming , data it comes from csv throw $.get

Answer (score 3):

By the time you're dealing with a string in JavaScript, you're dealing with UTF-16. It's up to the browser to ensure that any data it passes to the JavaScript layer has been transformed correctly.

In this case, because you're using `$.get`, that means that the ajax layer has to know what it's dealing with. You'll need to ensure that your server is returning the correct charset information in the HTTP response containing the CSV file, so the browser knows what format the character data is in. Once you're doing that, the browser should do any necessary transformation from the original to UTF-16 for JavaScript.

Specifically, if your CSV file is in the character set [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (sometimes people call that "ANSI" although it's not correct), this would be the `Content-Type` header your server should return with the file:

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=windows-1252
```

...but if your content is Japanese, I wouldn't think it would be in Windows-1252, which is a (very limited) Latin character set. If you're using Windows, it's more likely to be [Code Page 932](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), which would be:

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=Windows-31J
```

...or if you're using *nix, perhaps [EUC-JP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EUC-JP#EUC-JP):

```
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=EUC-JP
```

You can learn more about charsets in [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset). ([This article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky is also quite helpful.) Further information about JavaScript's strings can be found in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (but basically, each "character" in a JavaScript string is a UTF-16 word, which means characters requiring two words show up as two "characters" in the string — not ideal for some texts, particularly east-asian ones, but when it was being defined, RAM was still precious...).

Answer (score 1):

I use this functions:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Extracted from: http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com.ar/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is useful to you　↓

http://jsfromhell.com/geral/utf-8

Comment: Excuse me , can you put some sample data?

Comment: sorry what kind of data ? , Japanese text , or resulted text

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Japanese : 開催日 テーマ 講師(病院名) 講師(講師名) 詳細      and out data : �J�Ó� �e�[�} �u�t(�a�@��) �u�t(�u�t��) �ڍ�

Comment: This link is not working for me either. 
Even though I experimented with "%E2%80%93" known as "EN DASH" (U+2013 – e2 80 93)